# Cannot parse time as T when parsing RFC3339 string to time

Tags: go, string-to-datetime

I have a string from db , say

```
dbString := "2020-03-16 14:46:13 +0530 IST"
```

My requirement is to insert this string as Timestamptz into another table

I am trying to convert dbString into Time

```
timeToBeInserted := time.Parse(time.RFC3339,t.VO.DateLastModified)
```

I see the below error

```
+0000 UTC parsing time "2020-03-16 14:46:13 +0530 IST" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse " 14:46:13 +0530 IST" as "T"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your date string does not match [RFC3339](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) format:

```
RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
```

You should use a custom format. The following one works with your string:

```golang
dbString := "2020-03-16 14:46:13 +0530 IST"
fmt.Println(time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", dbString))


// Output:
// 2020-03-16 14:46:13 +0530 IST <nil>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your time string isn't in RFC3339 format, so don't tell `time.Parse` that it is. Instead use

```
time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", t.VO.DateLastModified)
```