# error with kubectl --since-time flag not recognizing datetime format

Tags: go, kubectl

I am taking a user input, "2023-09-02" (YYYY-DD-MM) and converting it to the specified datetime format(RFC3339) as specified in the official [docs](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_logs/):

> --since-time="": Only return logs after a specific date (RFC3339)

Here is the section responsible for the conversion:

```golang
date, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2023-09-02")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
since = date.String()
```

the error I get is:

> parsing time "2023-09-02" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "" as "T"

I altered the format according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60753957/cannot-parse-time-as-t-when-parsing-rfc3339-string-to-time) article and altered the code to:

```golang
date, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST", "2023-09-02")
```

the error that I get now is:

> parsing time "2023-09-02" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST": cannot parse "" as "15"

I understand that it's trying to parse the "15" of the hour but there isn't an hour provided. Is there a way to default it to midnight that day?

**edit**:
after changing it to:

```golang
d, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02", since)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
sinceTime = d.Format(time.RFC3339)
```

sinceTime = 2023-09-02T00:00:00Z

but when I use that month in kubectl the command freezes
`$ kubectl logs -n <NAME_SPACE> --container=<CONTAINER> -f --timestamps=true --since-time=2023-09-02T00:00:00Z --tail 500 -l app=<APP>`

**FIX**:
`d, err := time.Parse("2006-02-01", since)`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your layout string not matching your input.

If you specify your custom format string as `"2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST"` your input has to match it exactly, you can't just leave out the time-portion of the timestamp.

Note that the error message is saying that it is looking for the `"15"` part in your layout but can't find it (`cannot parse ""`) as there's nothing there.

If you just want to parse the date you can try:

```golang
t, err := time.Parse("2006-02-01", "2023-09-02")
```

Which will return the following timestamp

> 2023-02-09 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Without any explicitly stated time zone, it will always default to UTC.